# What is 'parent' in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, parent

I was introduced to the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
</div>

<div class="extra" style="color:green">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from its parent.
</div>

<div style="color:red">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inherit

I'm not sure why the colour of the extra span is green. When they use the 'inherit' value, do they take a colour similar to the first one introduced? Is that what it is?

What's the 'parent' and 'child' referring to here? What's their definition?

Comment: Parent element in this case is the div that the span is inside on.

Comment: <div id="somediv"><p>hello world</p> <div class="content"> <a hrf="#">somelink</a></div></div>

Comment: In my comment above somediv is the parent and everything inside that div is a child if i give style to parent and on children i say inherit it will take the style of the parent div

Comment: Yes, div class extra has inline css style that sets his color to green. The `.extra span { color:inherit; }` means that that div should inherit the color from this parent. http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `<span></span>` elements are nested within their 'parent' `<div></div>` elements, they are said to be 'children' of the 'parent' div.

```
<div id="parent">
  <span id="child1"></span>
  <span id="child2"></span>
  <span id="child3"></span>
</div>
```

The 3 spans are children of the parent div, and siblings of each other.  Much like a family.  When a child inherits styles from its parent, it uses the same style as its parent uses for that particular style.

```
color: inherit;
```

means that when assigning the span its color, it will defer to whatever the parent color is, which in this case was green.

Comment: Not clear. I don't know from your answer if `div#parent` will still be a parent if there will be another `div` inside `<div id="parent"><div><span><span></div></div>`

Comment: @Green the term `parent` is used to refer to the direct parent of a given element. In your example, the `div#parent` is not the parent of the `span`, because the untagged `div` occupies that role. But style inheritance is still trickle-down in this way, and so the span will still take the color of `div#parent` in your example, unless the untagged `div`, or it's child `span` is defined to have a different color, or, speaking more broadly, unless the nature of the element is inherently different. (A div defined in an inline parent will take block styling by nature)

Answer (score 5):

If we have a `<p>` inside a `<div>` element, the `<div>` is the parent of the `<p>` and the `<p>` is the child of the `<div>`

```
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

You can read this web: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp it explains perfectly.

> The nodes in the node tree have a hierarchical relationship to each other.
>
> The terms parent, child, and sibling are used to describe the relationships.
>
> - In a node tree, the top node is called the root (or root node)
> - Every node has exactly one parent, except the root (which has no
>     parent)
> - A node can have a number of children
> - Siblings (brothers or sisters) are nodes with the same parent

[image]

CSS uses this structure to make specific selectors like `first-child`, `:nth-child(n)`, `:last-child`...

You can see all CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

The value `inherit` of a CSS attribute applied to an HTML node, simply takes the parent value of the attribute.

So if I have an html like this:

```
<div>
   <p></p>
   <p class="red"></p>
</div>
```

And css like:

```
div {
   background-color: red;
}

div > p {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

The div with the red class, using `inherit` will take the value red of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

**inherit summary:** from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

> The inherit CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to
>   take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It is
>   allowed on every CSS property.

Brake down your code to single parts to understand what's going on like:

```
span {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This means every span has a blue color.

Moving on to next lines:

```
.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

This means every span inside an element with a `class="extra"` will inherit the color. Means all the `<span>`s inside `.extra` will take it's parent color.

Now as you see in your result every span has blue color, except the one inside the div with class `extra` which has an inline style on color saying it is green.

Answer (score -2):

In this, you have used both **Internal** and **Inline** styling at the same time. Since Inline styling has the **highest precedence** over **Internal** and *External* Styling that is why that extra span turns out to be Green.

Comment: Downvoting since the other answers provided in 2017 more clearly answer the question. While you are correct that inline styling has higher precedence, this particular span is gets its style from `.extra span {color: inherit;}`, which is saying to do whatever is declared by the parent.

Comment: It's great that you are participating the the shared knowledge of Stack Overflow but if you are going to answer and old question with several other high quality answers you will need to provide an answer that adds more substance to what has already been said.

Comment: This is not adding any useful information, other answers have already explained the problem.