# Is there a connection between parent elements in HTML and parent elements in CSS?

Tags: html

I am currently doing the CSS Codecademy course and I am confused whenever they say "parent element", I am not sure whether they are referring to the elements parent within HTML or if it means something else. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they're referring to parent elements on the HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 'parent' in HTML or CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827783/what-is-parent-in-html-or-css)